# Cannot access 'androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner'

Tags: java, android

Unfortunately, but for unknown reasons this class is underlined in red and the following message appears: Cannot access androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner.

How can I fix it?

How can I solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: add    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha02'   can sovle this problem

Comment: Add this line to your module’s build.gradle script:



dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
}

Answer (score 2):

an updated answer.
I had the same issue with

```
android.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1
```

so it's been fixed after I had switched to

```
androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As blue mei said, for me, changing androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0 to 1.3.0-alpha02 helped me solved the problem.

Comment: damm!  it's work. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too and none of the proposed fix helped; I got rid of the issue by selecting the **Invalidate Cache / Restart** function in Android Studio under the "File" menu.